# Laravel RESTful API NOT receiving data from cURL Request

Tags: php, rest, curl, laravel, laravel-4

So I have a "Skeleton" written for my projects' RESTful API. I've been trying to POST data to the store() function through cURL. And so I used

`if(Input::hasfile('file'))`

to check if the image/data was posting and it returned false. How would I actually detect the image/data if I were to post it via a cURL request similar to this

`curl.exe --user "admin:password" --header "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" --data-binary "@vok.png" --output "out.txt" --dump-header "header.txt" http://bitdrops.co/bitdrops/public/index.php/api/v1/drop/`

Ignore the header and response output.

This is my current code for the store() function.

```
public function store()
{
    $file = Input::file('file');
    $destinationPath = public_path() . '/uploads';

    $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
    //$extension =$file->getClientOriginalExtension(); 
    $upload_success = Input::file('file')->move($destinationPath, $filename);

    if( $upload_success ) {
        return Response::json('success', 200);
    } else {
        return Response::json('error', 400);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? Can we see the log?

Comment: First it was `Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on a non-object` Then I commented that line out just for shits and giggles and received `Call to a member function move() on a non-object`. So the problem is that the store() function isn't receiving or detecting the file sent from the cURL request. I'm just not sure why.

Comment: --data-binary "@vok.png" <- I don't see you passing the file as "file".

Comment: Ahh got it! I tried `curl.exe -i --user user:pass -F file=@vok.png --output "out.html" http://bitdrops.co/bitdrops/public/index.php/api/v1/drop` and it worked perfectly. Thank you so much for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: Certainly, I will provide it in the form of an answer so it is easier for the rest of the community to find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue appears that in your cURL statement

`curl.exe --user "admin:password" --header "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" --data-binary "@vok.png" --output "out.txt" --dump-header "header.txt" http://bitdrops.co/bitdrops/public/index.php/api/v1/drop/`

You are not passing the file as "file". As you commented earlier on the solution is:

`curl.exe -i --user user:pass -F file=@vok.png --output "out.html" http://bitdrops.co/bitdrops/public/index.php/api/v1/drop`